# Reference array keys without knowing their names?

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

If I have an array like this:

```
$array = array('something'=>array('more'=>array('id'=> 34)));
```

Then `print_r($array['something']['more']['id']` works fine.

But say the key names might change but the structure wont. How could I reference the same values without knowing the names?

I thought maybe `print_r($array[0][1][2]` might work, but of course those keys don't exist.

Comment: use foreach for associative arrray http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a [`foreach`](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php) statement. Use a recursive function to handle nested arrays (**untested**):

```
public function iterateNestedArray($array) {
    if (is_array($array)) {
        foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
            print_r(iterateNestedArray($value));
        }
    }
    else {
        return $array;
    }
}
```

You might consider implementing this function with a second argument to pass a callback function, rather than just `print_r`ing every value.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple possibilities.

You could use [arrayiterator](https://www.php.net/arrayiterator) or simply [foreach](http://nl.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php).
Perhaps even [array_values](http://nl2.php.net/array_values) could be your solution.

Answer (score 0):

you can do a straight loop with foreach, although it's fairly ugly:

```
foreach ( $grandparent as $gpkey => $parent ) {
    foreach ( $parent as $pkey => $child ) {
        foreach ( $child as $ckey => $value ) {
            print $gpkey . " - " . $pkey . " - " . $ckey . " = " . $value;
        }
    }
}
```

Or you can get the list of keys with `array_keys()`:

```
$keys = array_keys($array);
for ( $i=0, $imax=count($keys); $i<$imax; $i++ ) {
    print $key . " = " . $array[$key];
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use `reset()`, `next()` and `end()` as always

```
$array = array('something'=>array('more'=>array('id'=> 34)));
echo reset(reset(reset($array)));
```

Comment: -1 This code spits E_STRICT errors. `reset` accepts a reference, therefore `reset(reset())` is invalid (references must be variables; expressions, like function calls, are not accepted).